# identify the key in a dictionary that appears the maximum number of times, along with the number of times it appears

Tags: python, dictionary

Hoping someone can help:
I created a dictionary named stat_pair, and am trying to return the key with the maximum number of occurrences, along with the number of times the key appears.
I'm new to Python & tried several approaches, but haven't been successful.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Python dictionary keys are unique, so i'm not sure what you mean by number of occurrences?  Do you mean the key with the most values associated with it?

Comment: Obviously homework question. OP doesn't even understand the question, it seems. The only way this can make sense is if the input is a list of keys and the requirement is to build a dictionary and find out what key occurs most frequently in the input list.

Comment: are you creating a dictionary with (word, number of occurrences of word) pair?

Comment: Tony- yes I mean the key with the most values associated with it, and the number of values associate with it.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that tied keys all count as the winner:

```
keys_tied_for_most_occurences = [k for k in my_dict.keys()]
num_of_occurences = 1
```

Comment: Come on now, I know *some* of you can appreciate a good joke.